# Multiplication array using methods

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I'm new to coding and have been set a challenge of creating an method that prints out a multiplication array.

My code is as follows...

```
    public class TimesTableArray

{
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
 int size = 12;
 int number = 3;
 }
 
 
 private static int [] getTimesTable(int size, int number)
 {
     int[] timesTable = new int[size];
     
     for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
     {
         timesTable[i]  = number * (i +1);
     }
     return timesTable;
 }   
}
```

I get the following output...

```
3
6
9
12
15
18
21
24
27
30
33
0
```

I need the 12th item to read 36, not 0. I know it's to do with the index reads from 0 to 11, but I don't know how to amend my code to make this so.

Please could someone guide me on how to do this?

Comment: In the method `getTimesTable()` you need to start iteration from index `0` not `1`. And don't subtract one here `timesTable[i-1]`. Change it to `timesTable[i]  = number * (i + 1);`

Comment: You currently iterate from `1` to `size - 1`. That's one iteration missing. You need to iterate up to `size`. So `i <= size` instead of `i < size`.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko there is nothing wrong with iterating over an array starting with one.

Comment: @maloomeister forget the OP being a student, there is nothing wrong to iterate over an array starting with 1.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) license, for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question).

Answer (score 3):

You have a classic "off by one" error.

If you start at 1, then you INCLUDE the size, and have to subtract one to get the Index:

```
 for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++)
 {
     timesTable[i - 1]  = number * i;
 }
```

If you start at 0, then you EXCLUDE the size, and have to add one when you multiply:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
 {
     timesTable[i]  = number * (i + 1);
 }
```

You're going to have people swear up and down that one is correct and the other is wrong. This is down to preference. Do what "makes sense" to you.

Answer (score 0):

In the population loop, you are iterating from 1 rather than 0 but you do not offset the terminal condition.  I would rewrite you loop to follow the standard pattern rather than trying to bake in the offset.  So...

```
for (int index = 0 ; index < size ; ++index) { ... }
```

This will allow the index to line up naturally in the assignment.  Apply the offset in the calcuation.

```
timesTable[index] = number * (index + 1);
```

So you get...

```
private static int[] getTimesTable(int size, int number) {
  int[] timesTable = new int[size];
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    timesTable[i]  = number * (i+1);
  }
  return timesTable;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are having an *off-by-one* error. Since you want to have an array of 12 answers, starting with 1, your loop range has to be from 1 to 12 ***inclusive***. Therefore:

```
 private static int [] getTimesTable(int size, int number)
 {
     int[] timesTable = new int[size];
     
     for (int i = 1; i <= (size); i++)
     {
         timesTable[i-1]  = number * i;
     }
     return timesTable;
 }
```

The reason why your last index was zero, is because numeric array indexes are initialized to zero after instantiation (`new int[size]`).